# How to parse YOUTUBE JSON in JAVA & show in a list View

Tags: android, json, youtube-api

How Can I parse JSON YouTube data API v3 in JAVA?

[here is my json data](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResult=30&q=natok%20bangla%20mosharrof%20karim&key=AIzaSyCR40QlsuX0aFfBV-wEPDsH_jxna1tDFRA)

I want to show the data in a list view & after clicking a video will be played.
How can i do this?
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResult=30&q=natok+bangla+mosharrof+karim&key=AIzaSyCR40QlsuX0aFfBV-wEPDsH_jxna1tDFRA";

private static final String TAG_ITEMS = "items";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_ID_VIDEOID = "videoId";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TAG_THUMBANAILS_URL = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hlaX2OZ_kDg/default.jpg";
private static final String TAG_CHANNELTITLE = "channelTitle";

JSONArray items = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsList;

ListView lv = getListView();

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemslist;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    itemslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    new GetContacts().execute();
}
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                items = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEMS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String videoId = c.getString(TAG_ID_VIDEOID);
                    String channelTitle = c.getString(TAG_CHANNELTITLE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_ID_VIDEOID, videoId);
                    contact.put(TAG_CHANNELTITLE, channelTitle);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    itemsList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, itemsList,R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_DESCRIPTION,
                TAG_CHANNELTITLE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

here is my java code

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far. First learn JSON parsing in java. There are plenty of [tutorials on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=json+parsing+in+java). :)

Comment: i updated question with java code

Answer (score 0):

The [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) documentation provides sufficient samples and explanation for what you want to do.

For example, [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), if successfull, will return a JSONObject with items JSONArray as its child. You can get this JSONArray and pass it to your adapter.

For more information on how to get started with YouTube Data API, check out the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) page.